# Stacking Vector Layers in TileStache

Tags: python, tilestache, vector-tiles, stack, composite

I am serving several **vector tile layers** of different geometries (point, line & polygon) in [**TileStache**](http://tilestache.org/) using `VecTiles:Provider`,
 with this `cfg`file:

```
{
  "cache":
  {
    "name": "DISK",
    "path":"/tmp/stache",
    "umask": "0000" 
  },
  "layers": 
  {  
    "world":
    {       
        "allowed origin":"*",
        "projection": "spherical mercator",
        "provider":
        {
            "class": "TileStache.Goodies.VecTiles:Provider",      
            "kwargs":
            {
                "dbinfo":
                {
                    "host":"localhost",
                    "user":"postgres",
                    "password":"postgres123",
                    "database":"test"
                },
            "queries":
                {
                    "0":"SELECT geom AS __geometry__,name_0 FROM worldcountries1  -- zoom 0+"
                }
            }
        },
        "preview":{"ext":"json"}
    },
    "boundary":
    {       
        "allowed origin":"*",
        "projection": "spherical mercator",
        "provider":
        {
            "class": "TileStache.Goodies.VecTiles:Provider",      
            "kwargs":
            {
                "dbinfo":
                {
                    "host":"localhost",
                    "user":"postgres",
                    "password":"postgres123",
                    "database":"test"
                },
            "queries":
                {
                    "6":"SELECT geom AS __geometry__,name_2 FROM islamabad_bound  -- zoom 6+",
                    "7":"SELECT geom AS __geometry__,name_2 FROM islamabad_bound",
                    "8":"SELECT geom AS __geometry__,name_2 FROM islamabad_bound",
                    "9": null

                }
            }
        },
        "preview":{"ext":"json"}
    },
    "cartographic":
    {       
        "allowed origin":"*",
        "projection": "spherical mercator",
        "provider":
        {
            "class": "TileStache.Goodies.VecTiles:Provider",                        
            "kwargs":
            {
                "dbinfo":
                    {
                       "host":"localhost",
                       "user":"postgres",
                       "password":"postgres123",
                       "database":"test"                       
                    },
                "queries":
                {
                    "8":"SELECT geom AS __geometry__,name, priority,category, kind FROM cartographic WHERE kind IN ('parks','forests','water') -- zoom 8+",
                    "9":"SELECT geom AS __geometry__,name, priority,category, kind FROM cartographic WHERE kind IN ('parks','forests','water')",
                    "10":"SELECT geom AS __geometry__,name, priority,category, kind FROM cartographic WHERE kind IN ('parks','forests','water')",
                    "11":"SELECT geom AS __geometry__,name, priority,category, kind FROM cartographic WHERE kind IN ('parks','forests','water')",
                    "12":"SELECT geom AS __geometry__,name, priority,category, kind FROM cartographic WHERE kind IN ('parks','forests','water')",
                    "13":"SELECT geom AS __geometry__,name, priority,category, kind FROM cartographic WHERE kind IN ('parks','forests','water','industry','educational','graveyard','hospitals','religious places','parking places','port places','runway')",
                    "14":"SELECT geom AS __geometry__,name, priority,category, kind FROM cartographic WHERE kind IN ('parks','forests','water','industry','educational','graveyard','hospitals','religious places','parking places','port places','runway','building_low')"
                }

            }
        },
        "preview":{"ext":"json"}
    },
    "roads":
    {       
        "allowed origin":"*",
        "projection": "spherical mercator",
        "provider":
        {
            "class": "TileStache.Goodies.VecTiles:Provider",                        
            "kwargs":
            {
                "dbinfo":
                    {
                       "host":"localhost",
                       "user":"postgres",
                       "password":"postgres123",
                       "database":"test"                       
                    },
                "queries":
                {
                    "7":"SELECT geom AS __geometry__,name, priority FROM isl_roads WHERE priority IN (5,4) -- zoom 7+",
                    "8":"SELECT geom AS __geometry__,name, priority FROM isl_roads WHERE priority IN (5,4)",
                    "9":"SELECT geom AS __geometry__,name, priority FROM isl_roads WHERE priority IN (5,4)",
                    "10":"SELECT geom AS __geometry__,name, priority FROM isl_roads WHERE priority IN (5,4)",
                    "11":"SELECT geom AS __geometry__,name, priority FROM isl_roads WHERE priority IN (5,4,3,2)",
                    "12":"SELECT geom AS __geometry__,name, priority FROM isl_roads WHERE priority IN (5,4,3,2)",
                    "13":"SELECT geom AS __geometry__,name, priority FROM isl_roads WHERE priority IN (5,4,3,2)",
                    "14":"SELECT geom AS __geometry__,name, priority FROM isl_roads  -- zoom 14+"
                }

            }
        },
        "preview":{"ext":"json"}
    },
    "pois":
    {       
        "allowed origin":"*",
        "projection": "spherical mercator",
        "provider":
        {
            "class": "TileStache.Goodies.VecTiles:Provider",                        
            "kwargs":
            {
                "dbinfo":
                    {
                       "host":"localhost",
                       "user":"postgres",
                       "password":"postgres123",
                       "database":"test"                       
                    },
                "queries":
                {
                    "12":"SELECT geom AS __geometry__,name, priority FROM isl_pois_priority WHERE zoom_level = 12 -- zoom 12+",
                    "13":"SELECT geom AS __geometry__,name, priority FROM isl_pois_priority WHERE zoom_level IN (12,13)",
                    "14":"SELECT geom AS __geometry__,name, priority FROM isl_pois_priority WHERE zoom_level IN (12,13,14)",
                    "15":"SELECT geom AS __geometry__,name, priority FROM isl_pois_priority WHERE zoom_level IN (12,13,14,15)",
                    "16":"SELECT geom AS __geometry__,name, priority FROM isl_pois_priority WHERE zoom_level IN (12,13,14,15,16)",
                    "17":"SELECT geom AS __geometry__,name, priority FROM isl_pois_priority WHERE zoom_level IN (12,13,14,15,16,17)",
                    "18":"SELECT geom AS __geometry__,name, priority FROM isl_pois_priority WHERE zoom_level IN (12,13,14,15,16,17,18)",
                    "19":"SELECT geom AS __geometry__,name, priority FROM isl_pois_priority WHERE zoom_level IN (12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19)",
                    "20":"SELECT geom AS __geometry__,name, priority FROM isl_pois_priority WHERE zoom_level IN (12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20) -- zoom 20+"
                }

            }
        },
        "preview":{"ext":"json"}
    }
  }
}
```

To render the tiles on the web I am making use of [The GeoJSON plugin in Leaflet](https://github.com/glenrobertson/leaflet-tilelayer-geojson) to individually call the layers. Each tile layer corresponds to a single JSON layer.

```
var geojsonURL = 'http://localhost:8080/roads/{z}/{x}/{y}.json';
    var geojsonTileLayer = new L.TileLayer.GeoJSON(geojsonURL, {
            clipTiles: true,
            unique: function (feature) {
                return feature.id; 
            }
        }, {
            style: style,
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                if (feature.properties) {
                    var popupString = '';
                    for (var k in feature.properties) {
                        var v = feature.properties[k];
                        popupString += k + ': ' + v + ' ';
                    }
                    popupString += '';
                    layer.bindPopup(popupString);
                }
                if (!(layer instanceof L.Point)) {
                    layer.on('mouseover', function () {
                        layer.setStyle(hoverStyle);
                    });
                    layer.on('mouseout', function () {
                        layer.setStyle(style);
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    );
    map.addLayer(geojsonTileLayer);
```

I have looked into the [Composite](http://tilestache.org/doc/TileStache.Goodies.Providers.Composite.html) and [Sandwich](http://tilestache.org/doc/TileStache.Sandwich.html) providers in **TileStache** but they seem to **only work for Raster data**, I can't get them to work on my Vector Tile Layers.

Can I use the `Composite` provider to **stack/merge** the **vector tile layers**, or is there any other way to return all my tiles in a **single JSON**?

**Update:** I have found a way to merge multiple`GeoJSONs` using [python](https://gist.github.com/migurski/3759608) , how can I integrate this into `TileStache` so that I can use this like the `composite` provider (something like [custom provider](http://tilestache.org/doc/#custom-providers) perhaps, though I can't figure out how to make it work exactly)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I am able to get all the layers in a single layer, a "composite" by using the `MultiProvider` provider in the class and just passing it the layers I want in the composite as the arguments. It results in a single `JSON` file that contains all of my layers. This is the layer I added in the `cfg`

```
    "composite":
        {
            "allowed origin":"*",
            "provider":
            {
                "class": "TileStache.Goodies.VecTiles:MultiProvider",
                "kwargs":
                {
                    "names": [ "boundary", "cartographic", "roads", "pois"]
                }
            }
        }
```